# Java HashSet remove(e) method doesn't behave as I expected

Tags: java, collections

I am unable to understand the logic behind it.

Case 1:

```
HashSet shortSet = new HashSet();
    for (short i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        shortSet.add(i);
        shortSet.remove(i - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(shortSet.size() + "    shortSet : " + shortSet);
```

Op :**Size : 3    shortSet : [0, 1, 2]**

Case 2 :

```
HashSet shortSet = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        shortSet.add(i);
        shortSet.remove(i - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Size : "+shortSet.size() + "    shortSet : " + shortSet);
```

Op : **Size : 1    shortSet : [2]**

*I just want to understand the main reason behind this, why these two output are different Just By changing from **short** to **int*** . what happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that in the first case, the expression `i` is of type `short`, whereas the expression `i - 1` is of type `int`. Those values are being boxed to `Short` and `Integer` respectively - the `Integer` isn't in the set, so can't be removed.

You can fix this with a cast:

```
for (short i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    shortSet.add(i);
    shortSet.remove((short) (i - 1));
}
```

In your *second* case, both `i` and `i - 1` are of type `int` (then boxed to `Integer`), so the entries you're adding can also be removed...

Comment: @DavidWallace: It really does, IMO... I'll add more though. Better now?

Comment: Oops, sorry.  You're quite right.  I needed to read it twice.  I have reversed my downvote.

Comment: You are right, if you want to remove a short element from the shortSet you could try: shortSet.remove((short)(i - 1));

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are trying to remove Integer, because i-1 expression is promoted to Integer. In your HashSet you have only Shorts so that's the reason why it doesn't remove anything.

Btw since Java 1.5 you shouldn't use raw type of any collections.